# How to migrate Nexternal eCommerce site users to Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, data-migration

I am using a Nexternal eCommerce site. Is there any tool or service available for migrating from Nexternal eCommerce site to my new Magento 1.9 site?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello, we can help you at this. Visit our profile to get to know about our experience in shopping cart data migration.

Comment: OK, Thank you.
But I couldn't find "Nexternal eCommerce" from your backend. Do you have service for "Nexternal eCommerce" to "Magento 1.9" data migration?

Comment: Don't worry about not seeing "Nexternal eCommerce" in our supported cart list. We are expanding the network and surely your current platform will be added. For your migration from Nexternal eCommerce to Magento, you can create custom request so our developers will take care of the rest.

Comment: We'd recommend you choose Magento 2.x over Magento 1.9 since Magento 1.x has reach its end of life date lately in June.